# How to properyly change permissions for Absences in Project-Open

Tags: permissions, project-open

We have a Problem with Absences:

1. A User who created an Absence can not edit the Absence after wards :(
2. After a user's Absence was approved he/she can still delete the absence :(

How to set the permissions for absences?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your absence is controlled by a [workflow](https://www.project-open.com/en/package-acs-workflow), is that correct? There are two parameters controlling the behavior, so the correct solution would be to create copies of the permission functions and to set the parameters AbsenceNewPageWfEditButtonPerm and AbsenceNewPageWfDeleteButtonPerm accordingly. Please see the [source code](https://www.project-open.net/api-doc/content-page-view?path=packages%2Fintranet-timesheet2%2Fwww%2Fabsences%2Fnew.tcl&version_id=48279&source_p=1) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the file

```
packages/intranet-timesheet2/tcl/intranet-absences-procs.tcl
```

which contains the permission matrix `im_absence_new_page_wf_perm_table`

Unfortunately the permissions do not get effective immediately - a restart of project-open causes the permissions to be active.

A better solution would be desired - but at least it works :/